How to hide a custom tabBar?
I use a custom tabBar in my app. I hides default bar view and create a new view with rounded corners. In some view controllers I want to hide my tabBar. I use this code to do it:
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.isHidden = true

And my tabBar is hidden, but the custom view called tabBarView inside the TabBarViewControler is not hidden. How to fix this?
code in TabBarViewControler class:
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    let tabBarView = UIView()
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .systemChromeMaterialLight))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        generateTabBar()
        setupView()
        setupTabBarAppearance()
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        view.addSubview(tabBarView)
        tabBarView.addSubview(blurView)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(tabBar)
        tabBarView.bringSubviewToFront(blurView)
    }
    
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
            guard let barItemView = item.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else { return }

            let timeInterval: TimeInterval = 0.38
            let propertyAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: timeInterval, dampingRatio: 0.9) {
                barItemView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.9, y: 0.9)
            }
            propertyAnimator.addAnimations({ barItemView.transform = .identity }, delayFactor: CGFloat(timeInterval))
            propertyAnimator.startAnimation()
        }
    
    func generateTabBar() {
        
        let tableViewController = TableViewController()
        let favoritesController = FavoritesController()
        let searchViewController = SearchViewController()
        let settingsViewController = SettingsViewController()
        
        let vc1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableViewController)
        vc1.tabBarItem.title = tableViewController.title
        vc1.tabBarItem.image = tableViewController.tabBarImage
        
        let vc2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: favoritesController)
        vc2.tabBarItem.title = favoritesController.title
        vc2.tabBarItem.image = favoritesController.tabBarImage
        
        let vc3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchViewController)
        vc3.tabBarItem.title = searchViewController.title
        vc3.tabBarItem.image = searchViewController.tabBarImage
        
        let vc4 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: settingsViewController)
        vc4.tabBarItem.title = settingsViewController.title
        vc4.tabBarItem.image = settingsViewController.tabBarImage
        
        viewControllers = [vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4]
    }
    
    private func setupTabBarAppearance(){
        
        tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear
        tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered
        tabBar.tintColor = mainColor
        tabBar.itemSpacing = 5
        
        tabBarView.backgroundColor = .white
        tabBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        tabBarView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1.0).cgColor
        tabBarView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
        tabBarView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        tabBarView.layer.shadowRadius = 20
        tabBarView.layer.cornerRadius = (tabBar.frame.size.height+20)/2
        
        tabBarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: tabBar.frame.size.height+20).isActive = true
        tabBarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -SafeArea().bottom()).isActive = true
        tabBarView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: SafeArea().left()+40).isActive = true
        tabBarView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -SafeArea().right()-40).isActive = true
        
        blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blurView.clipsToBounds = true
        blurView.layer.cornerRadius = (tabBar.frame.size.height+20)/2
        
        blurView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBarView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        blurView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBarView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        blurView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBarView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        blurView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBarView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        tabBar.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        tabBar.frame.origin.y = tabBar.frame.origin.y - SafeArea().bottom() - 10
    }
}


Just tabBarView.isHidden = true? Am I missing something?

What about if you create a function to hide inside of your TabBarViewController to hide the view where you  are adding the subviews.
